CiviCRM problem with Contribution email confirmation
Adter recent security update 5.78.2 some of civicrm Contact started reciving confirm email after reciving transaction in CRM.
Some after card manthly payment(automated), some after CSV transaction import - in this proces we dod not change anything, all transactions are made in the same way like before
We noticed diffrence with activity, before upgrade alle Contributons had coresponding activity "Contribution" with title for ex "10$ - My payment for this NGO"
No we it's "Payment" activity with title "10$ - Payment for Contribution"
We can't find any source of this change in CRM, not any setting, issue, bug report but for us it's larg problem because lot of contact don't wan't to recive thos emails after payment.
Email template the they reciving is "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)" in workflow messages

